# Python and Pandas - Determining if a bill is overdue

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have a dataframe that has timeseries and categorical data.

```
  ╔═════════════════════════════════════════════╗
  ║ Name       BillDate             Bill Status ║
  ╠═════════════════════════════════════════════╣
  ║ Company A  2015-07-22 15:51:00  Paid        ║
  ║ Company B  2015-01-31 12:01:00  Unpaid      ║
  ║ Company C  2016-01-12 00:00:00  Unpaid      ║
  ╚═════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I am trying to add another column telling me if the bill is overdue based on two factors. First factor is if the current date is BillDate+180 days or more, and the second is Bill Status is unpaid.

I am probably being dense on how to how to do this. My thinking is to do the following:

```
   billpayperiod = timedelta(days = 180)
   currentdate = datetime.now()
   df['Bill Due Date'] = df['BillDate'].apply(lambda x: x + billpayperiod)
```

Then create some function that will check to see if

```
 currendate > Bill Due Date and Bill Status = unpaid. 
 If True = Overdue
 If False = No Due,
 If Bill Status = paid, then Paid.
```

I appreciate your thoughts on: 
1. Does this method make sense and
2. Help creating the function that performs the check

Since I am much better in excel, this is what I would do using that:

```
  Create the Bill Date + 180 column (name it DueDate
  Set a cell = currentdate
  Create a new column: formula    IF(BillStatus="Paid","Paid",IF(AND(BillStatus="Unpaid",currentdate>DueDate),"Overdue","Not Overdue"))
```

Comment: show us the code to create the dataframe.

Comment: I am actually pulling data from excel, any tips or a primer on how to create a dataframe looking like the one above?

Comment: your second requirement doesn't make sense you have a condition which will then set overdue else no due but then you use the same condition again to say it's paid???

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Should be if Bill Status = Paid, then Paid.

Comment: OK, updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC this will do what you want:

```
In [21]:
df[(((df['BillDate'] - dt.datetime.now()).dt.days).abs() > 180) & (df['Bill Status'] == 'Unpaid')]

Out[21]:
        Name            BillDate Bill Status
1  Company B 2015-01-31 12:01:00      Unpaid
```

We can call [`dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html#pandas.Series.dt.days) on the timedeltas and compare the absolute values:

```
In [25]:
(df['BillDate'] - dt.datetime.now()).dt.days

Out[25]:
0   -182
1   -354
2     -8
Name: BillDate, dtype: int64

In [24]:
(df['BillDate'] - dt.datetime.now()).dt.days
((df['BillDate'] - dt.datetime.now()).dt.days).abs()

Out[24]:
0    182
1    354
2      8
Name: BillDate, dtype: int64
```

**EDIT**

To set your new statuses you can define a couple masks and use `np.where`:

```
In [29]:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
overdue = (((df['BillDate'] - dt.datetime.now()).dt.days).abs() > 180) & (df['Bill Status'] == 'Unpaid')
paid = (df['Bill Status'] == 'Paid')
df['new status'] = np.where(paid, 'paid', np.where(overdue, 'overdue', 'no due'))
df
​
Out[29]:
        Name            BillDate Bill Status new status
0  Company A 2015-07-22 15:51:00        Paid       paid
1  Company B 2015-01-31 12:01:00      Unpaid    overdue
2  Company C 2016-01-12 00:00:00      Unpaid     no due
```

Comment: What I am trying to do take something like this 

          df[(((df['BillDate'] - dt.datetime.now()).dt.days).abs() > 180) & (df['Bill Status'] == 'Unpaid')

Have that create a string of either "Paid", "Overdue", or "Not Due" based on the factors shown. Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Apologies for my noob-ness but I am getting an error when trying to run the code. 
My error is 
       
      name 'dt' is not defined

I am importing pandas as pd, and from datetime import datetime, timedelta

Is there anything else I need to import to get the code to work?

Comment: try `import datetime as dt`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add a column in pandas using

```
#create columns 'newStatus' and set default to No due
df['newStatus'] = 'No Due'
```

Then you can use .loc and the indices from the answers above to set it to specific values

```
df.loc[indices,column] = value
```

for example:

```
#create indices for unpaid bills, and for bills that are due
iUnpaid = df['Bill Status']=='Unpaid'
iDue = (((df['BillDate'] - dt.datetime.now()).dt.days).abs() > 180)

#update corresponding values
df.loc[iUnpaid & iDue,'newStatus'] = 'Due'
df.loc[iUnpaid & ~iDue,'newStatus'] = 'No Due'
```